# How to use navCtrl with a class name retrieved from LocalStorage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am developing a game in ionic 3, my class names are as follows: level1, level2, level3, etc... And I am using LocalStorage to save the level that the user reached.

The code is as follows:

```
import { level1 } from '../levels/level';
import { level2 } from '../levels/level';
import { level3 } from '../levels/level';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/Storage';

...

storage.get('levelNumber').then((val) => {

if(val == null)
{
   this.levelNbr = level1
}
else
{
   this.levelNbr = val
}

this.navCtrl.push(this.levelNbr)
//when the class name is retrieved from storage it and placed in val it is then 
//assigned to levelNbr, so now levelNbr should contain the class name and
//then pushed in navCtrl.
```

And the code to save the level in LocalStorage is as follows:

```
this.storage.set('levelNumber', "level2")
//does not work with navCtrl.push() as "level2" is a string
this.storage.set('levelNumber', level2)
//does not work as it throws cannot clone error
```

The problem here is that when I save the class name as string in LocalStorage, it does not work in the `navCtrl.push` when I retrieve it, instead it must be of class type I guess. And saving it in LocalStorage as class throws an error "cannot clone".

How can I dynamically check which level the user reached in LocalStorage and then push the class level automatically?

I thought of solving this by simply doing a switch case however its not feasible for 100 levels.

Thank you

Comment: You can alternatively (to the answer) make all your levels as lazy loaded, then loading those is via their string title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ways to cleverly import things into one variable like `import * as levels from '../levels/level';` but if you don't want to touch your imports I'd do

```
const levels: any = { level1, level2, level3 }; //"any" because I'm lazy.
```

levels["level1"] will now give you the import.

And I imagine your scenario will be something like:

```
storage.get('levelNumber').then((val) => {
    this.levelNbr = levels[val];
    ...
});
```

I haven't tested anything here. Use the code with a grain of salt. (sorry, I already said I'm lazy.)

Comment: Wow that worked!! thanks!! for documentation i used the string format for localstorage: this.storage.set('levelNumber', "level2")